# How to Save or Update the changed Values of DICOM images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dicom

I am working on DICOM images in MATLAB. I want to know `how to save the changed values of dicom images in MATLAB` .I have read the DICOM image and performed the following steps.

> dicomread('dcm_image.dcm');
>
> info=dicominfo('dcm_image.dcm');

Value of `PatinetName` is `Usman`

> info.PatientName
>
> ans =
>
> Usman

Now i have changed the value of `PatientName` to `Khan`

> info.PatientName='Khan';
>
> info.PatientName
>
> ans =
>
> Khan

Here after this step I want to know how i am going to save my changed values, So that when i `>>clear` the matlab and run `>>dicominfo('dcm_image');` command it should show me the changed value of `PatientName` which will be `Khan`.

Regards,

Comment: I think cneller already gave you the right answer. You need to write the dicom Image to save your changes. e.g. `dicomwrite(X, 'thefilename.dcm', info);` just as explained in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomwrite.html

*Note* that this likely is fine when dealing with files in a testing environment, but DICOM instances are not designed to be changed as such. If you want to insert this data back into another system, you will want to change the identifiers associated with the instance (and series/study/patient identifiers depending on what has changed). Ideally, the system itself will have a mechanism of making such a change that can be properly logged.